# Scala Futures - flatMap and onFailure

Tags: scala, monads, future

If I have some computation that takes a while I might place it in a `scala.concurrent.Future`:

```
val f = Future { someLongRunningFunction() }
```

and let's say I want to do something else asynchronously once that computation is completed:

```
f.flatMap{ _ => anotherLongRunningFunction() }
```

In the event that `f`'s initial block fails, how do I "idiomatically" handle this when using `flatMap` or other combinators? Is it merely a case of using `recover` or `onFailure` before the `flatMap`?

I like the elegance and simplicity of using a `flatMap` but it seems failure scenarios get in the way of it.

**Edit**: the second future is reliant on the first, hence the `flatMap`. I'm looking for a solution that'll elegantly let me chain like I would with `flatMap` but also handle failures of the first.

Comment: Does the second method depend on the result of the first at all? Do you  care about the returned value of either?

Comment: Yes it does, hence the ordering.

Comment: Ok, well.. what happens if `f` fails? Why should be bother running the second future if it depends on the first? How can we recover? What do you want to happen and when?

Comment: I want to tell it what to do just like I would with `onFailure` but I'm wondering if there's a means of using `flatMap` and telling it what to do `onFailure` in an elegant way. Presumably it's just a `onFailure` then `flatMap` call. i.e. using just `flatMap` doesn't handle failures.

Answer (score 3):

If you have several futures you can put them in a for comprehension.

```
val futureResult = for {
    result1 <- future1
    result2 <- future2
    ...
} yield {
    //computation with results
}
```

You can add a `recover` at the end in case you want to process any exception you may find:

```
futureResult.recover{
    case exceptionResult: Throwable => // Process exception
}
```

I think this is more clean that using `flatMap`.

Comment: I don't think the OP necessarily wants to `recover` at the end--it's unclear. This is just re-hashing the `flatMap` into a for-comprehension.

Comment: Exactly. Future 2 is dependent on the Future 1 completing first; hence the flatMap call.

Comment: In that case, have a look at the [scala async library](https://github.com/scala/async). It may also help. But if you need to complete the first future first, I would resolve it, check the results and then resolve the second one. The `flatMap` will join both computations.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the scaladoc for [flatMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$):

> Creates a new future by applying a function **to the successful result**
>   of this future, and returns the result of the function as the new
>   future.  **If this future is completed with an exception then the new
>   future will also contain this exception**.

Notice the bold, meaning that whatever you pass to flatMap will only be executed if the initial future completes successfully.

So you should only handle the result of the entire execution:

```
val result = future1.flatMap {
    result => functionReturningFuture2(result)
}
```

and then:

```
result.onFailure // or
result.onSuccess // or
result.recover
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only starting with Future, but here are some ideas.

If you really want to use `flatMap`, you have to turn the failure into a success.

```
for{ a <- f recover r
     b <- another(a)
} yield b
```

This works if the return type of `r` is `:>` the result type of `f`.

Or you can pass the problem of what to do with the failure on to the next process

```
for{ a <- f map (x => Success(x)) recover (ex => Failure(ex))
     b <- another(a)
} yield b
```

Here the argument type of `another` would be `Try[T]` where the type of `f` is `Future[T]`.